# Magento - Apply Tax On Custom Quote Totals Field

Tags: magento

I have created a surcharge module for Magento which adds a custom total field to the quote. The surcharge is input into Magento including tax. I have successfully got the module adding the surcharge to the quote and the grand total is correct on the checkout page.

My issue comes when trying to apply tax to the surcharge so that it gets included and displayed in the tax field on the checkout page. Currently it only includes the tax for the products and the shipping.

I have managed to calculate the tax for the surcharge but cant't get the tax applied to the quote so that it is displayed in the tax field but also don't think my approach is quite correct either. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
class ********_Deposits_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Surcharge extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract {

 protected $_config = null;

 public function __construct()
 {
    $this->setCode('surcharge_price');
    $this->_config      = Mage::getSingleton('tax/config');
    $this->_store = Mage::app()->getStore();
 }

 protected function _calculateTax(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
{
    $calculator     = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation');
    $inclTax        = $this->_config->priceIncludesTax($this->_store);

    $taxRateRequest = $calculator->getRateRequest(
        $address,
        $address->getQuote()->getBillingAddress(),
        $address->getQuote()->getCustomerTaxClassId(),
        $this->_store
    );

    $taxRateRequest->setProductClassId(Mage::getStoreConfig('********/surcharges/tax_class', $this->_store));

    $rate = $calculator->getRate($taxRateRequest);

    $baseTax = $tax = $calculator->calcTaxAmount($address->getBaseSurchargePriceAmount(), $rate, $inclTax, true);


}

/**
 * Collect address subtotal
 *
 * @param   ********_Surcharges_Model_Quote_Address $address
 * @return  ********_Surcharges_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Surcharge
 */
public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
{

    parent::collect($address);

    $this->_setAmount(0)->_setBaseAmount(0);

    // If Surcharges Is Enabled Then Calculate Away :-)
    if(Mage::getStoreConfig('********/surcharges/surcharge_enabled')) {

      $items = $this->_getAddressItems($address);
      if (!count($items)) {
          return $this;
      }

      // Calculate Total Surcharge For Items In Quote (Base Prices!)
      $surcharge = 0.0;
      foreach ($items as $item) {
        $price = $item->getData('base_surcharge_price', null);
        if(isset($price)) {
          $surcharge += $item->getData('base_surcharge_price') * $item->getQty();
        }
      }

     $this->_setAmount($surcharge);
     $this->_setBaseAmount($surcharge);

     $this->_calculateTax($address);
    }


    return $this;
}

public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
{

  if(Mage::getStoreConfig('********/surcharges/surcharge_enabled')) {
    $surcharge = $address->getSurchargePriceAmount();
    if(isset($surcharge) && $surcharge > 0) {
      $address->addTotal(array(
          'code'  => $this->getCode(),
          'title' => Mage::getStoreConfig('********/surcharges/surcharge_label'),
          'value' => $surcharge
      ));
    }
  }

  return $this;
}

public function getLabel()
{
    return Mage::getStoreConfig('********/surcharges/surcharge_label');
}
```

Comment: Hi Ashley did you manage to get this working?

Comment: Hi Jonathan. I did in the end by effectively recalculating the tax amount son the address objects. See post below!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to solve this this using the following code. Not the best solution but spent hours trying to do it and didn't get anywhere fast. Asterix's need to be replaced.

```
class *****_Deposits_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Surcharge extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract {

 protected $_taxConfig = null;

 public function __construct()
 {
    $this->setCode('surcharge_price');
    $this->_taxConfig      = Mage::getSingleton('tax/config');
    $this->_store = Mage::app()->getStore();
 }

 protected function _calculateTax(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
{
    $calculator     = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation');
    $calculator->setCustomer($address->getQuote()->getCustomer());

    $inclTax        = $this->_taxConfig->priceIncludesTax($this->_store);

    $taxRateRequest = $calculator->getRateRequest(
        $address,
        $address->getQuote()->getBillingAddress(),
        $address->getQuote()->getCustomerTaxClassId(),
        $this->_store
    );

    $taxRateRequest->setProductClassId(Mage::getStoreConfig('*****/surcharges/tax_class', $this->_store));

    $rate = $calculator->getRate($taxRateRequest);

    if($rate > 0.0) {
      $baseTax = $calculator->calcTaxAmount($address->getBaseSurchargePriceAmount(), $rate, $inclTax, true);
      $tax = $address->getQuote()->getStore()->convertPrice($baseTax, false);

      $address->addTotalAmount('tax', $tax);
      $address->addBaseTotalAmount('tax', $baseTax);

      $rates = array();
      foreach ($address->getAppliedTaxes() as $rate) {
        $rate['amount'] = $rate['amount'] + $tax;
        $rate['base_amount'] = $rate['base_amount'] + $baseTax;
        $rates[] = $rate;
      }

      $address->setAppliedTaxes($rates);

      if($inclTax) {
        $address->setGrandTotal($address->getGrandTotal() - $tax);
        $address->setBaseGrandTotal($address->getBaseGrandTotal() - $baseTax);
      }
    }

}

/**
 * Collect address subtotal
 *
 * @param   *****_Surcharges_Model_Quote_Address $address
 * @return  *****_Surcharges_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Surcharge
 */
public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
{

    parent::collect($address);

    // Clear Cached Values As Multiple Addresses Causes Values To Be Added Twice Otherwise!
    $this->_setAmount(0)->_setBaseAmount(0);

    // If Surcharges Is Enabled Then Calculate Away :-)
    if(Mage::getStoreConfig('*****/surcharges/surcharge_enabled')) {

      $items = $this->_getAddressItems($address);
      if (!count($items)) {
          return $this;
      }

      // Calculate Total Surcharge For Items In Quote (Base Prices!)
      $surcharge = 0.0;
      foreach ($items as $item) {
        $price = $item->getData('base_surcharge_price', null);
        if(isset($price)) {
          $surcharge += $item->getData('base_surcharge_price') * $item->getQty();
        }
      }

     $this->_setAmount($address->getQuote()->getStore()->convertPrice($surcharge, false));
     $this->_setBaseAmount($surcharge);

      $this->_calculateTax($address);
    }


    return $this;
}

/**
 * Assign subtotal amount and label to address object
 *
 * @param   *****_Surcharges_Model_Quote_Address $address
 * @return  *****_Surcharges_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Surcharge
 */
public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
{

  if(Mage::getStoreConfig('*****/surcharges/surcharge_enabled')) {
    $surcharge = $address->getSurchargePriceAmount();
    if(isset($surcharge) && $surcharge > 0) {
      $address->addTotal(array(
          'code'  => $this->getCode(),
          'title' => Mage::getStoreConfig('*****/surcharges/surcharge_label'),
          'value' => $surcharge
      ));
    }
  }

  return $this;
}

/**
 * Get Surcharge label
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getLabel()
{
    return Mage::getStoreConfig('*****/surcharges/surcharge_label');
}
```

}

Comment: its not working magento 1.7 can any body give me solution for 1.7

Comment: This works fine in Magento 1.7. It's what I developed it for. This is not the complete solution, only part of it. Read the question in full and you will get some pointers as to how this module was achieved.

Comment: Note that you need to make the total be calculated <after>tax</after> in the config.xml.. Otherwise tax total Collection will null all taxes and this code will have no effect.