# Magento custom surcharge leads to wrong cart calculation

Tags: php, magento

for one of our customers I wrote a custom shipping extension including a specific surcharge if a special attribute is set. As soon as I activate the surcharge class via the config.xml file of the module, the calculation is wrong. Even if I don't override any code an just access the parent implmetation. If I install my custom module on a blank Magento shop running the same Version 1.9.1.0 it works. So I also tried to set the same configuration parameters in the admin panel for System> configuration > sales > tax

This is the calculation as it should be. I have one Article in my shopping cart including tax.

```
Subtotal (without Tax)  3,69 €
Subtotal (incl. Tax)    3,95 €
Grandtotal without Tax  3,69 €
Tax                     0,26 €
Grandtotal inkl. Tax    3,95 €
```

And this is what happens when I include the surcharge node in my config.xml

```
Subtotal (without Tax)  3,95 €
Subtotal (incl. Tax)    3,95 €
Surcharge               4,00 €
Grandtotal without Tax  7,95 €
Tax                     0,26 €
Grandtotal incl. Tax    8,21 €
```

The node in the config xml is include like this:

```
    <config>
    <global>
    <sales>
        <quote>
            <totals>
                <surcharge>
                    <class>***_***_Model_Total_Quote</class>
                </surcharge>
            </totals>
        </quote>
    </sales>
    </global>
    </config>
```

And this is the actual implementation. As mentioned earlier it makes no difference if I actually implement collect or fetch or if I just call the parent implementation.

```
<?php
class ***_***_Model_Total_Quote extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract
{
public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
{
    parent::collect($address);

    if (($address->getAddressType() == 'billing')) {
        return $this;
    }

        $surcharge = $this->_getSurcharge();
        $this->_addAmount(Mage::app()->getStore()->convertPrice($surcharge));
        $this->_addBaseAmount($surcharge);

    return $this;
}
public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
{
    if (($address->getAddressType() == 'billing')) {

            $address->addTotal(array(
                'code' => 'surcharge',
                'title' => $this->_getTitle(),
                'value' => $this->_getSurcharge()
            ));
    }
    return $this;
}

private function _getSurcharge()
{
    return Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/***/***');
}

private function _getTitle()
{
    return Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/***/title');
}
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910686/magento-apply-tax-on-custom-quote-totals-field/13512470#13512470. Possibly multiple addresses and the collect method being called multiple times. You can clear this using $this->_setAmount(0)->_setBaseAmount(0);

Comment: collect only gets called two times. For billing and for shipping. Already saw your post and tried that with no effect. :/